# Changing pixel values using QGIS raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

How could I convert values of 32767 to 0 using raster calculator in QGIS?

Answer (score 11):

If you have SAGA installed you could use the raster calculator in QGIS processing (SAGA-> Grid - Calculus-> Raster calculator) with the formulae:

```
ifelse(a=32767, 0, a)
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used [GDAL_Calc (python script)](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) to change one value (or a range of values) into 0. This can be achieved because `False` is 0 (`True` is 1) on the conditional statement. The calculation is `Condition * Raster`, where the condition is `True` the output is the raster value, where it is `False`the value is 0.

Using the 3rd example:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=0
```

The conditional statement becomes:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A!=32767)"
```

Which is true wherever the raster is not equal (!=) to 32767.

Answer (score 3):

If your raster layer name is `RasterA`, QGIS Raster Calculator expression is:

```
("RasterA@1" != 32767) * "Raster@1"
```

The logic has been clearly explained by @MichaelStimson, but just for clarity...

- `("RasterA@1" != 32767)` is `0` if the cell value is `32767`.
- Otherwise `("RasterA@1" != 32767)` is `1`.