# Change raster values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I need to change the values of a tif file.
Values less than 1.5 must be changed to zero. How can I do?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Which research did you do?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

Check this older post: [Changing pixel values using QGIS raster calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129481/changing-pixel-values-using-qgis-raster-calculator)

Using the answer from @Havard Tveite; if you have SAGA installed, use the `raster calculator`, `SAGA-> Raster - Calculus-> Raster calculator` with this formula:

```
ifelse(a<1.5, 0, a)
```

Check with your data if values that equal 1.5 have to be changed as well.

If you do not have SAGA installed, check the answer of @Kazuhito for a `QGIS Raster calculator` approach