# Change select color in a raster in QGIS using Serval or Value tool

Tags: qgis, raster, erdas-imagine

Is it possible to edit the table view of a raster that you see in the Value tool?

Alternatively

Using Serval, once we have a selection polygon can we choose a specific range of raster values within that polygon and then just change those selected values within the polygon and not the whole polygon?

https://github.com/lutraconsulting/serval/blob/master/Serval/docs/user_manual.md

If the value to change is 39 for example and you want to select all 39's within the selection and change them to 60. The paint tool changes all the values within the polygon but I want just 39 to be changed to 60.

In ERDAS it looks like below.
[image]

and in QGIS it is
[image]

but I can't see a way to just change a single value within the selection.

I have considered approaches like GDalCalc but they seem to save a new raster each time. I need to review and change multiple areas in the same file. [Changing pixel values using QGIS raster calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129481/changing-pixel-values-using-qgis-raster-calculator)

The ThRasE plugin is also really good but doesn't allow me to use the main qgis window. Is there anything similar that works as a toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coding this in pyqgis.

It expects a 'mask' layer with the 1st three fields here. It fills the values in based on what you change in the raster.

[image]

In the python code add in the name of the raster layer that needs to be edited. See

```
# Define parameters
raster_layer_name = 'cvmsre_t54hyg_e2021_ae8m4'
vector_layer_name = 'mask'
```

- Select the polygon to edit
- Run the script
- Enter in the values in the popup
- Hit Ok

Here's the basic working code.

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject, QgsLayerTreeLayer, QgsField, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QSpinBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class CustomInputDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomInputDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Input Values")

        # Setup layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Add form layout for inputs
        formLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.oldValueInput = QSpinBox(self)
        self.oldValueInput.setMinimum(1)
        self.oldValueInput.setMaximum(10000)
        self.oldValueInput.setValue(200)  # Default value
        formLayout.addRow("Old Value:", self.oldValueInput)

        self.newValueInput = QSpinBox(self)
        self.newValueInput.setMinimum(1)
        self.newValueInput.setMaximum(10000)
        self.newValueInput.setValue(1)  # Default value
        formLayout.addRow("New Value:", self.newValueInput)

        self.noteInput = QLineEdit(self)
        formLayout.addRow("Note:", self.noteInput)

        layout.addLayout(formLayout)

        # Add OK and Cancel buttons
        buttonsLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.okButton = QPushButton("OK", self)
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.okButton)

        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

        layout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

    def getValues(self):
        return (self.oldValueInput.value(), self.newValueInput.value(), self.noteInput.text())

# Usage
dialog = CustomInputDialog()
if dialog.exec_():
    old_value, new_value, note = dialog.getValues()
    print(old_value, new_value, note)
else:
    print("Operation cancelled by user.")
# Convert single old_value to list for compatibility with the script
old_values = [old_value]

# Define parameters
raster_layer_name = 'cvmsre_t54hyg_e2021_ae8m4'
vector_layer_name = 'mask'

# Fetch layers by name
raster_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(raster_layer_name)[0]
vector_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(vector_layer_name)[0]

# Check and add necessary fields to the vector layer if they do not exist
fields_to_add = [
    ('Orig_Vals', QVariant.String),
    ('New_Val', QVariant.Int),
    ('Note', QVariant.String)
]

vector_layer.startEditing()
for field_name, field_type in fields_to_add:
    if vector_layer.fields().indexFromName(field_name) == -1:
        vector_layer.addAttribute(QgsField(field_name, field_type))
vector_layer.commitChanges()
vector_layer.updateFields()

if not vector_layer.selectedFeatureCount():
    print("No features selected in the vector layer.")
else:
    raster_ds = gdal.Open(raster_layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), gdal.GA_Update)
    rb = raster_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    raster_arr = rb.ReadAsArray()

    # Creating an in-memory layer for the selected features
    mem_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('Memory')
    mem_ds = mem_driver.CreateDataSource('memDS')
    mem_layer = mem_ds.CreateLayer('memLayer', geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
    layer_defn = mem_layer.GetLayerDefn()

    # Transfer selected features to the memory layer
    for feature in vector_layer.selectedFeatures():
        geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(feature.geometry().asWkb())
        mem_feature = ogr.Feature(layer_defn)
        mem_feature.SetGeometry(geom)
        mem_layer.CreateFeature(mem_feature)

    # Rasterize the selection
    mask_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', raster_ds.RasterXSize, raster_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    mask_ds.SetGeoTransform(raster_ds.GetGeoTransform())
    mask_band = mask_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(mask_ds, [1], mem_layer, burn_values=[1])

    mask_arr = mask_band.ReadAsArray()

    for old_value in old_values:
        raster_arr[(mask_arr == 1) & (raster_arr == old_value)] = new_value
    rb.WriteArray(raster_arr)

    vector_layer.startEditing()
    for feature in vector_layer.getSelectedFeatures():
        feature['Orig_Vals'] = ','.join(map(str, old_values))
        feature['New_Val'] = new_value
        feature['Note'] = note
        vector_layer.updateFeature(feature)
    vector_layer.commitChanges()

    rb = None
    raster_ds = None
    mask_ds = None
    mem_ds = None

raster_source_uri = raster_layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
raster_layer_name = raster_layer.name()

QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(raster_layer.id())

refreshed_layer = QgsRasterLayer(raster_source_uri, raster_layer_name)
if refreshed_layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(refreshed_layer, False)
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.findGroup('ChangeRaster')
    if not group:
        group = root.addGroup('ChangeRaster')
    group.addLayer(refreshed_layer)

print("Updated and reloaded layer")
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```